# Azure Data Factory unable to connect to SQL Server in VM - Error 11402

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I am getting this very generic error when trying to connect to a SQL Server instance within VM. Any ideas why? Thanks

> Error 11402
>
> The value of the property '' is invalid: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'.
> Value does not fall within the expected range.

Linked Service window below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems like you're specifying a parameter named `''` so, since we can't see your screen over your shoulder, how exactly are you doing that?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I updated my question with a screenshot. I did not add any parameters from what I understand

Comment: Why do you use Autoresolve Integration runtime? Do you have SHIR installed?

Comment: Possibly relevant, [Lesson Learned #296:The value of the property '' is invalid: Value does not fall within the expected](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/lesson-learned-296-the-value-of-the-property-is-invalid-value/ba-p/3721700)

Comment: @Aswin Just a convenience thing for a quick POC. Does it make a difference?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I tried giving Contributor role to the Data Factory Managed Identity earlier too.

Comment: According to the link theat @AlwaysLearning provided, this could be a _very cryptic_ network error. If you are using _Autoresolve Integration runtime_ then you need to allow incoming connections from it's _unknown_ ip address into your VM. A better way to do this is install self hosted runtime on to the VM with the SQL Server, and that will solve most of your network issues.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it works now after I switched to Self Hosted Runtime. Rechecked the documentation and it says so too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a **Self-Hosted Integration Runtime**.

According to the [Microsoft link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#considerations-for-using-a-self-hosted-ir), since the data store (SQL Server in my case) is hosted within a VM, **Self-Hosted Integration Runtime** is the solution

[image]

Comment: It's not _the_ solution but it's certainly the most secure. Does your PoC _require_ SQL on a VM? Because a quick PoC for me would be using Azure SQL. That is far quicker and easier to set up than SQL on a VM

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, in our real-world scenario our SQL is hosted on the Azure VM. Of course, Azure SQL will be the fastest way to do a quick POC. Thanks for your input!

Comment: While SHIR is a valid answer, it's not the only one.  You can use an Azure integration runtime with a managed vnet.  I've had to do this for 3 SQL Servers on VMs.  It was a bit of a pain though because I had to setup a load balancer, a health probe, backend pools / load balancing rules / front end ip config / private link service for each SQL Server.  Then create private endpoints from the data factory to the private link services and approve them.  PITA, but it works.